# Does display_rotate still work?

Tags: boot, hdmi, display, config.txt

I'm trying to use this runtime config.txt parameter under Raspbian Stretch and an external LED monitor on the HDMI port to no effect. It's hard to tell from posts here and elsewhere if this setting only effects the Pi display or external displays as well.

Comment: Where do you get the parameter `display_rotate`? I can't find it in `boot/config.txt` or in `/boot/overlays/README`.

Comment: Rotate_LCD=2 gives me a rotation of 180° on the LCD ribbon output and doesn't effect the HDMI. I'm sure I've seen HDMI rotation in the /boot/config.txt file. Not near a Pi at the mo but will update when I'm home.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

display_rotate is deprecated in favor of display_hdmi_rotate but it still doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

`display_rotate=2`

will turn the HDMI display upside-down whereas

`lcd_rotate=2`

will turn the directly attached touchscreen display (not HDMI) upside-down.  I've seen reports that say this may not work with certain touchscreen display models though.